# How to create a project template in IntelliJ containing javascript files?

Tags: templates, intellij-idea

When I create a *project* template in IntelliJ (Tools>Save Project as Template) and the project contains javascriptfiles with a "{" inside, then, when creating a new project, I get a Velocity Error: "Error parsing file template: Encountered "{" at..." and the javascriptfile is empty in the new project.
(Creating javascript *file* templates works fine)
Any idears?

Comment: Is the { at the beginning of the file or just occurs in the file?

Comment: @Harmelodic: The line is `$.ajax({`. But now I've found a work around: `jQuery.ajax({`. Looks like a error in the Velocity parser in IntelliJ

Comment: There we go. Ensure next time to include your code in your question. It may be that you've just got a bug that something like Velocity is mis-reading.

Comment: I totally agree.  The post was made in frustration, before I had taken the time to analyze the probleme.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this problem dynamically (without knowledge of the content of the javascript file)?